# Python tkinter - Button with command lamba: doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I wrote this script with Python tkinter and Selenium.
I create a button, when we click on it, 2 functions have to be executed. But I don't know why, it doesn't work well, only the first one: login() is executed and the second one: kalk() will not be executed.

**If I put all the lines of the 2 functions in only one function, it works until the end without any problem.**

**Why does the below code not work ?**

Here is the code (only a part of the program):

```
def login():
    boutoncount.config(state='disabled')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Bat02\Desktop\Python\Selenium Test\chromedriver.exe")
    browser.get('url')
    time.sleep(10)
    login= browser.find_element_by_id("UserID")
    pwd = browser.find_element_by_id("Password")
    confirm= browser.find_element_by_id("LogIn")
    login.send_keys(loginentry.get())
    pwd.send_keys(pwdentry.get())
    time.sleep(3)
    confirm.click()

def kalk():
    time.sleep(10)
    kalknum= browser.find_element_by_id("txt_Kalk")
    eigkalkuncheck=browser.find_element_by_id("chk_Kalk")
    eigkalkuncheck.click()
    kalknum.send_keys(user_entries[0].get())

boutoncount=Button(fenetre,text="count",width=800,height=1,bg="white", font="bold",bd=5, command=lambda:[login(),kalk()])
boutoncount.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Thank you !

Comment: My advice is to not combine `lambda`. Just create a proper function. It will make the code easier to read, easier to understand, and easier to debug.

Comment: Why do you think the second command isn't working? Given the number of sleeps you use, it will be at least 23 seconds before  it does anything useful.

Comment: Avoid using `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. Try changing the code to use `<tkinter Widget>.after(time_in_ms, function)`

Comment: can you add the full code

Comment: mainly the code to create the button

Comment: Thanks all for your answer.
  ==>Bryan Oakley: The sleep is to let time between the different tasks since the website with which the code has to interact needs different and VARIABLE time to refresh its page

  ==>The Lizzard: I will try, one question: why should we avoid time.sleep with tkinter ?

  ==>PDHide: the code for the button is in the code in the request post: "boutoncount=Button"...

Comment: Latiole: The reason to avoid using `sleep()` is because it prevents tkinter's mainloop from running which will cause the GUI to freeze until the delay is over. Using `after()` avoids that.